# How to efficiently get count for item in list of lists in python

Tags: python

I have three lists as follows.

```
mylist = [[5274919, ["my cat", "little dog", "fish", "rat"]], 
          [5274920, ["my cat", "parrot", "little dog"]], 
          [5274991, ["little dog", "fish", "duck"]]] 
myconcepts = ["my cat", "little dog"]
hatedconcepts = ["rat", "parrot"]
```

For each concept in `myconcepts`, I want to get the count every other concept connected to it using `mylist`. Then remove the `hatedconcepts` from it. So, my output should looks like as follows.

```
{"my cat": [("my cat", 2), ("little dog", 2), ("fish", 1)],
"little dog": [("little dog", 3), ("my cat", 2), ("fish", 2), ("duck", 1)]}
```

I was using this code to do it.

```
import collections
myoutput = []
for concept in myconcepts:
    mykeywords = []

    for item in mylist:
        if concept in item[1]:
            for mykeyword in item[1]:
                if mykeyword in hatedconcepts:
                    pass
                else:
                    mykeywords.append(mykeyword)
    if len(mykeywords) > 0:            
        sorted_keywords = collections.Counter(mykeywords).most_common()
        myoutput.append(tuple((concept, sorted_keywords)))
print(myoutput)
```

The output of the code is:

```
[('my cat', [('my cat', 2), ('little dog', 2), ('fish', 1)]), ('little dog', [('little dog', 3), ('my cat', 2), ('fish', 2), ('duck', 1)])]
```

However now I have a huge `mylist` with a size of 3GB and nearly 9000 `myconcepts`. The `hatedconcepts` count is only 20. It looks like it takes about two weeks to run using my current code. The main reason for this could be that my current program is `O^3` which is not very efficient. Therefore, I am looking for ways to make my current program more efficient. I am even fine with pythonic solutions that even take 5-6 days to run. Please let me know your thoughts.

I have added a portion of `mylist` in: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3EhIRwwKwD3Kv4zDsmXaH1D73tx0eF3/view?usp=sharing just to get some idea how it looks like.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: when you said it takes two weeks to run. Do you mean the entire code or just the collections.Counter part?

Comment: you need to use  the cpu for help! did you think in spawning threads and sending them to work on deffrent list slices?. this is right if the list lays in `ram` if the list lays in a file then threads wont help you (`IO Bound process`)

Comment: Why are you using Python for this?

Comment: You might consider using a SQL database for this if your dataset is so large.

Comment: you can try using spark or hadoop for this job they are good at word count examples, also distributed

Comment: Does is have to be a list of lists? Could you convert it to a list of sets? E.g. `mylist = [{"my cat", "little dog", "fish", "rat"}, {"my cat", "parrot", "little dog"}, {"little dog", "fish", "duck"}]`

Comment: @ShubhamJain I updated the code in my question. :)

Comment: @EmJ does the result have to be sorted?

Comment: @SayandipDutta yes, it needs to be sorted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to make it fast, avoided some repeated loops. Please check if this speeds things up.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

database = defaultdict(set)
output = {}

# created a map for different concepts, so we only search the indices where a certain concept is
for index, (_, concepts) in enumerate(mylist):
    for concept in concepts:
        database[concept].add(index)

for concept in myconcepts:
    search_indices = database[concept]
    all_counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(mylist[i][1] for i in search_indices))
    for hc in hatedconcepts:
        if hc in all_counts: all_counts.pop(hc)
    output[concept] = sorted(all_counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I will run this and let you know how it performed :)

Comment: thanks a lot once again. I tested and this seems to work pretty fast. from `tqdm` it expects this to run from nearly a day which is great. thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

As other comments and answers have indicated, this operation is better handled by Spark or a database. That said, here's my take on it, I introduced some sets operations and minimized repeated loops.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def get_counts(lst, concepts, hated_concepts):
    result = {concept: defaultdict(int) for concept in concepts}

    concepts_set = set(concepts)
    hated_concepts_set = set(hated_concepts)

    for _, inner_list in lst:
        # ignore hated concepts
        relevant = set(inner_list).difference(hated_concepts_set)

        # determine which concepts need to be updated
        to_update = relevant.intersection(concepts_set)

        for concept in to_update:
            for word in relevant:
                result[concept][word] += 1

    return result
```

Output is below. You mention the output "must be sorted", but it's unclear to me what the desired sorting is. Some timing tests indicate this is 9x faster than the code you provided on your sample data.

```py
{
    'my cat': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'my cat': 2, 'fish': 1, 'little dog': 2}), 
    'little dog': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'my cat': 2, 'fish': 2, 'little dog': 3, 'duck': 1})
}
```

#### Performance Improvement

```
emj_functn avg 0.9355s
get_counts avg 0.1141s
```

Performance testing script:

```py
import random
import string
import time

words = list({
    ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(5))
    for _ in range(1000)
})
test_list = [[random.randint(1e6, 1e7), [random.choice(words) for _ in range(100)]] for _ in range(1000)]
test_concepts = [random.choice(words) for _ in range(100)]
test_hated_concepts = [random.choice(words) for _ in range(50)]


def emj_functn(lst, concepts, hated_concepts):
    ...


def get_counts(lst, concepts, hated_concepts):
    ...


TEST_CASES = 10

start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(TEST_CASES):
    emj_functn(test_list, test_concepts, test_hated_concepts)
end_time = time.time()
avg = (end_time - start_time) / TEST_CASES
print(f'emj_functn avg {avg:.4}s')

start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(TEST_CASES):
    get_counts(test_list, test_concepts, test_hated_concepts)
end_time = time.time()
avg = (end_time - start_time) / TEST_CASES
print(f'get_counts avg {avg:.4}s')
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i will run this and let you know how it performed :)

Comment: thanks a lot once again. I tested and this seems to work pretty fast. thank you. however, since Sayandip posted the answer first and also includes the sorting, I marked it as the answer. Nevertheless, your suggested approach is fast too. For anyone who is reading my question, I recommend this method too :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
from collections import Counter
req={}
for i in myconcepts:
    x=sum([j[1] for j in mylist if i in j[1]],[])
    x=[i for i in x if i not in hatedconcepts]
    req[i]=dict(Counter(x))
print(req)
```

output:

```
{'my cat': {'my cat': 2, 'little dog': 2, 'fish': 1}, 'little dog': {'my cat': 2, 'little dog': 3, 'fish': 2, 'duck': 1}}
```

Comment: I get the following error in your code: `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` :)

Comment: if can you share the part of your data where it is misbehaving, I can help you with that.

Comment: I used the example given in the question to run your code :)

Comment: thank you for the edit. For some reason, I still get the same error. do you know why? :)

Comment: @EmJ did you miss the `[]` part at the end in `x=sum([j[1] for j in mylist if i in j[1]],[])` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) or [Apache Hadoop](https://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) if you have a word-count-like example, in fact, these frameworks specialize in that.

Both have frameworks have can be used with python.

But if you want to stick with only python.

I would suggest parallelization:

Split `my_list` into `n` sublist `my_sub_lists`

```
my_list = ["my cat", "little dog", "fish", "rat", "my cat","little dog" ]
# split my_list into n=2 sublists
my_sub_lists = [["my cat", "little dog", "fish"], ["rat", "my cat","little dog"]]
```

Compute item counts for `my_sub_lists` in parallel

```
Process 1: Counter(["my cat", "little dog", "fish"])
Process 2 : Counter("rat", "my cat","little dog"])
```

You would get some intermediate aggregation. `my_sub_counts`

```
my_sub_counts = [{"my cat":1, "little dog":1, "fish":1}, {"rat":1, "my cat":1,"little dog":1}]
```

Merge intermediate result to get the final item count.

```
result = {"my cat":2, "little dog":2, "fish":1, "rat":1}
```

Combining intermediate aggregation would be easier since it would be smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is coming a bit late now, but just to throw my answer out there.

I hadn't noticed `bphi`'s answer before I wrote mine. The idea is almost identical, but this answer comes out sorted.

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

s_myconcepts = set(myconcepts)
s_hatedconcepts = set(hatedconcepts)

myoutput = defaultdict(list)
for _, item in mylist:
    item = set(item)
    for concept in item.intersection(s_myconcepts):
        myoutput[concept].extend(item - s_hatedconcepts)

myoutput = {k: Counter(v).most_common() for k, v in myoutput.items()}
```

Comment: One important thing to note, is that since we are using `set` objects, we are assuming each `concept` shows up only once (or is counted only once) per `item` in `mylist`. From looking at your sample dataset, that seemed to be a safe assumption.

Comment: Upon closer look, some of the items in your list have the same concept listed multiple times. So the counts resulting from this solution might not be correct. Entry `5274923` is an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice question with a nice example dataset.

You should be able to get it down to run times of a couple of hours and using only a very small amount of memory by adopting a **streaming accumulator** architecture.

I note that the contents of the sublists are very regular just lists with repeated nesting structure and strings that don't *contain* any square brackets themselves. This allows following the following strategy:

**Define a chunk_size** that is ideally  more than twice the number of characters in the text decribing asublist from the file, I used ~2Megs.

**Read** the next chunk_size chars from the file into a buffer.

**Use a [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/17kfVl/1).finditer** to extract successive sub_lists from the buffer

**eval() each sub_list then run an Accumulator** class instance on the result to increment the counts according to your inclusion/exclusion rules.

**repeat for all sub_lists** in the buffer

**save the characters not used** at the end of the buffer by finditer

**repeat for the next buffer from the file**, (prepending any characters not used at the end of the previous buffer)

**Extract the running totals from the Accumulator** instance when the file is exhausted.

I first found the phrases used the most in your 11meg example then used the 1st, 3rd and 5th for a test list of words to include and the 2nd, 4th and 6th for words to exclude.

I had two ways of solving the problem so I could compare results to make sure they tally.

1. **Simple:** Just read in the whole file, eval it, then apply the Accumulaor to each sub-list
2. **Streaming**: Chunked as described above.

**The Simple solution takes two thirds of the time** of the Streaming, so it is faster (when you can fit everything in memory).

**The Streaming solution takes 1/150th of the memory** of the Simple solution and should stay pretty constant in memory use for larger file sizes whereas the Simple solution will need ever more memory.

The Streaming solution took less than 5 seconds to run with the 11 meg file so could take a few hours for 11 Gig files.

I intend to write a blog post on this which will show my final code.